# How can I pass null as a value for aggregate field from python?

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite, vega, vegas-viz

I would like to achieve this:

```
"$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "mark": {"type": "bar", "tooltip": true},
  "encoding": {

    "x": {"field": "Creative Type", "type": "nominal", "aggregate": null},
    "y": {"field": "Creative Type", "type": "nominal", "aggregate": "count"}
```

I am passing the values from Python to vegalite.
Since Python does not have a null keyword, I don't know how to set the value for aggregate as null in the x axis. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Python has None instead of Null

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent of null keyword in Python will be None. Please check if that works.

Answer (score 0):

In general, passing `None` in Python/Altair will result in `null` in JSON/vega. For example, when hiding a legend (`"legend": null` in Vega-Lite) you can use `legend=None` in Altair, as mentioned in [Adjusting the Legend](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html#adjusting-the-legend).

In the case of aggregates, however, that will not work: according to the Vega-Lite schema, `null` is not a valid argument for `aggregate`, and so attempting this in Altair will result in a `SchemaValidationError`.

If for some reason you really want to produce this invalid specification, you can do so by passing `validate=False` to `alt.Chart.to_json`:

```py
import altair as alt
chart = alt.Chart().mark_bar(tooltip=True).encode(
    x=alt.X('Creative Type:N', aggregate=None),
    y=alt.Y('Creative Type:N', aggregate='count')
)
print(chart.to_json(validate=False))
# {
#   "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.8.1.json",
#   "config": {
#     "view": {
#       "continuousHeight": 300,
#       "continuousWidth": 400
#     }
#   },
#   "encoding": {
#     "x": {
#       "aggregate": null,
#       "field": "Creative Type",
#       "type": "nominal"
#     },
#     "y": {
#       "aggregate": "count",
#       "field": "Creative Type",
#       "type": "nominal"
#     }
#   },
#   "mark": {
#     "tooltip": true,
#     "type": "bar"
#   }
# }
```